# MVC 5 Website - Shared Hosting - Medium Trust

Tags: medium-trust, asp.net-mvc-5

I recently hosted an asp.net MVC 5 website on shared hosting of hostgator. Its throwing me security errors. I contacted the support and they replied me that the website has to be Medium trust. They cannot offer Full trust as its shared hosting plan. I cannot opt for dedicated server as its too expensive.

My question is can't we build asp.net mvc 5 websites with medium trust. I marked trust level to Medium in web.config and its throwing few other errors. I added [assembly: AllowPartiallyTrustedCallers] to AssemblyInfo.cs. Not much of use.

How to build an asp.net MVC website with medium trust level? I am using Entity Framework.

Thanks,
Fayaz

Comment: I updated my code, switching from MVC 5 to MVC 4 and is working fine with medium trust. I learnt that should ask about trust level also, while purchasing webhosting :)

Comment: Yeap, you need to ask it next time. But, most of hosting provider offer full trust hosting now. :)

Comment: @Fayaz could you please explain how you managed to compile the MVC 4 project using Medium trust?

Comment: @Rossco Unfortunately there is no easy way. I first updated web config to medium trust and as it recommends, changed the code.